# External SD card not being recognised; data intact on card

Tags: external-sd, data-recovery, system-error, formatting

I have a HTC One M8 running Android KitKat 4.4.2, and I recently got a Sandisk 64GB MicroSD. Today a few of my apps have greyed out icons and when I click them, it says `app isn't installed`.

When I go to `Settings > Storage`, External SD shows as Unavailable. `Mount SD card` shows, but clicking it just shows a message saying `Preparing SD card` and it does nothing else.

It also keeps popping up with `Preparing SD card` at random.

Putting the memory card in my PC, the data is intact. I've tried restarting my phone a couple of times; no joy. Is there anything I can do to make this work again?

Failing that, am I safe to backup the data to my PC, format the SD card, and restore the files; and everything will work as it did?

Comment: It looks like it's possibly a counterfeit SanDisk card - Glad I backed my data up, it's totally dead now.

Comment: SanDisk have confirmed it as a counterfeit.

Answer (score 0):

The card was confirmed as a counterfeit by the manufacturer over the phone.